Declare pointer to function whose signature is not known
I would like to declare a variable which is a pointer to a function with an unknown signature.
For example, to declare a variable which can contain a pointer to a function which can be set to log.Printf I could go:
var foo func(format string, v ...any)

...
foo = log.Printf

But this assumes the function signature is known - in C++ I would use decltype but I can't find anything similar in Go. I tried reflect but couldn't make it work.
Anyone got any ideas?

Use reflection with interface, that way you will be able to use any function with interface. I made some changes and tested it on playground
package main

import (
    "log"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    var foo any = log.Printf
    dynamicFunction(foo, "Pointer, %s!", "Test")
}

func dynamicFunction(fn any, args ...any) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(fn)
    in := make([]reflect.Value, len(args))

    for i, arg := range args {
        in[i] = reflect.ValueOf(arg)
    }

    v.Call(in)
}

https://go.dev/play/p/fdDwDc46jbn

Use the share button on the playground to create a link. There is no reason to take a screenshot of the playground.

That's nice, thanks - I modified it so it wraps it in a lambda
https://go.dev/play/p/6U8ZqeTkZ04

Although this removes the compile time argument type checking I was hoping for...
